# Django Displaying Menu/Sub Menu

Tags: python, django

I am trying to displaying Menu and Sub Menu in table format like

```
Menu1
Menu2

   SubMenu1
   SubMenu2
   SubMenu3

Menu3
   SubMenu4
   SubMenu5
   SubMenu6
Menu4
```

So far, I was able to come up with below code but its not showing any record.

Views.py

```
def getCompleteMenuList():
    return Menu.objects.getMenuListing(id)

#mainMenuObj=Menu.objects.getMenuListing(id)
return render_to_response('manageMenu.html', {'title': menu_title,'name':name,'mainMenu':getCompleteMenuList,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Models.py

```
def getMenuListing(self, id):
    mainMenus = self.filter(parent_menu=0,business=id).order_by('order')
    result = []
    menus = []

    for menu in mainMenus:
        menus.append(menu)
        submenu = self.filter(parent_menu=menu,business=id).order_by('order')
        if submenu.exists():
            result.append(submenu)

    return dict(zip(menus, result))
```

template.html

```
{% with mainMenu.items as pop_menus %}
    {% for key, value in pop_menus %}
    display main menu rows
        {% for data in value %}
    display sub menu rows                                   
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}    
{% endwith %}
```

Current Situation I have 5 rows in table with 4 as parent_menu =0  and 1 as parent_menu = 1 (which exists).

When I try to print mainMenus its show 4 menu object.

```
< Menu: Menu object >, < Menu: Menu object >, < Menu: Menu object >, < Menu: Menu object >
```

But when I print menu inside for loop it only print 1 Menu object
Menu object

Can you please advise what I am doing wrong or is there any other way to achieve same thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way of accessing your model methods, firstly you have to have an object of the Class which your method belongs to 
Ex:

```
m = Menu.objects.get(id=foo)
```

foo is just an example it has to be some value corresponding to your id.

Then call the method you created on the models.py file through the object passing the required arguments
Ex:

```
menus = m.getMenuListing(id)
```

Now you have the correct data in the variable menus.
Try it this way.

Answer (score 0):

at this line..

`return dict(zip(menus, result))`

Your `menus` and `result` length are not equals and therefore the [zip() function as described here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)..

> The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest
>   argument sequence.

the dictionary will be truncate to length of menus.

Apart from your html template try unit test with getMenuListing() result.

Comment: Any suggestion, how can I achieve workaround here? Because as requirement, I might have submenu for menu.